# Snowpark connection errors with 0.6.0 jar

Tags: scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use snowpark(0.6.0) via Jupiter notebooks(after installing Scala almond kernel).  I am using Windows laptop.  Had to change the examples here a bit to work around windows.  Following documentation here

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/quickstart-jupyter.html

Ran into this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.snowflake.snowpark.Session$
  ammonite.$sess.cmd5$Helper.<init>(cmd5.sc:6)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd5$.<init>(cmd5.sc:7)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd5$.<clinit>(cmd5.sc:-1)
```

Also tried earlier with IntelliJ IDE,got bunch of errors with missing dependencies for log4j etc.

Can I get help.

Answer (score 0):

Have not set it up in Widows but only with Linux.

You have to do the setup steps for each notebook that is going to use Snowpark (part from installing the kernel).

It's important to make sure you are using a unique folder for each notebook, as in step 2 in the guide.

What was the output of the import $ivy.`com.snowflake:snowpark:0.6.0`?